# Misleading error message when questions list fails to load

Tags: feature-request, error-message

I browsed MSE front page a minute ago, and was greeted with the following error message:

> It was not possible to perform this tag search at this time due to an unexpected error.

Screenshot:

> [image]

I did not search for any tags...

Can the message please be changed to something more meaningful?

Comment: You do realize you broke the tag engine and with that summoned @MarcGravell *on a saturday* ... bad things will happen to you ...

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: [Me too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295404/162102), on a per-site meta.

Comment: I've been getting this a fair bit since yesterday... on a bunch of sites, main and meta

Comment: Got this recently on [ruSO](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VPsYj.png). I'm going to translate it, but afraid of lost it due to text changing if your request will be accepted :)

Comment: @DavidPostill caching? I don't think so. I've been noticing the same thing for about 3-4 days now, then it comes back to being ok after a minute or so. This being for any tags on StackOverflow.com Edit: matter of fact, I just saw it again a minute or so ago.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Why is this a feature request? Seems to be more of a bug, as per another post I saw while Googling this error: [Random errors on various sites when viewing main page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295433/231583)

Comment: @Fred-ii- David was using a [meta meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/221414#221414), didn't mean it seriously. As for feature request, it's because I ask to change the message to be more meaningful, not to fix the bug causing it, which might indeed deserve a separate bug report if happening frequently. (For me it happened just once so far, but from comments here looks like it's more frequent)

Comment: @ShadowWizard *Hehe,* got it. [I posted a related on question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348639/1415724) on Stack's meta also. Others are experiencing it as well.

Comment: From the *software's* perspective, a search over ***all*** tags is still a tag search :) but yes, we should improve that message - from the *user's* perspective, it really wasn't a "tag search"; as for what happened: apparently the tag engine got unhappy; we've restarted the nodes, and it is on my list to look at further

Comment: @MarcGravell I take it that your comment *"as for what happened: apparently the tag engine got unhappy; we've restarted the nodes"* is relevant to [this Stack meta question I posted earlier...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348639/1415724), yes? Plus, a few comments I left in the comments thread.

Answer (score 13):

The short summary of this one is "because internet"; it turns out some annoying folks were doing annoying things specifically to be annoying, and a side-effect was disproportionate performance impact to a particular sub-system (the "tag engine"). I sincerely doubt that it was accidental or simply "oops my innocent crawler had an impact on your site? I simply didn't know...", based on the pattern of behaviour and the particular hoops they jumped through to hide their tracks. Anyway, as far as annoying bots go: that's what we call "a day with a 'y' in"; it was low-key enough not to set off any *too urgent* alarm bells, but it made it onto our radar, as has now been squished.

Comment: Thanks, what about the message itself? Will you change it in case such thing will happen again?

Comment: @ShadowWizard yes, I'll try to look at that ASAP, but frankly I *hope* that you just don't see that message...

Comment: Three and half years later, did you have a chance to look at it?

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask unrelated; for a few seconds when we deploy, it can be a little... "uncertain" - we deployed a little while before your comment, so I'm guessing you were one of the first people on a fresh server

Comment: All good, I don't complain about the downtime itself, just the message. Pure nitpicking. :-)

Comment: And it became relevant again: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360522/it-was-not-possible-to-perform-this-tag-search-at-this-time-due-to-an-unexpected