# Strange tag-related error message on visiting a per-site meta

Tags: bug, per-site-meta, error-message

I visited [Beer, Wine, and Spirits Meta](https://alcohol.meta.stackexchange.com/), from the supercollider, and got this cryptic error instead of a list of questions:

[image: It was not possible to perform this tag search at this time due to an unexpected error]

Say what?  I wasn't searching tags, as you can see from the URL.

This persisted through several refreshes over a few minutes, but as I finished composing this question the site returned to normal behavior.  So the site isn't currently broken, but this error message seems misplaced so I'm still reporting it.  This isn't the error we normally get for read-only mode, temporary server errors, or 404.  Perhaps something is bubbling up from lower-level code without being caught, like maybe something having to do with favorite or ignored tags?  (Of which I have none, by the way.)

Comment: The engine was too drunk may be ;-)

Comment: Also I faced this problem, once. I can't remember, which site was it, but probably the physics SE. The problem disappeared after a page refresh. The message happened after a longer pause in the usage of the site (maybe 8-10 hrs or so), but my cookies still lived. I had multiple browser tabs to various SE sites open concurrently. This time I used chrome from iOS.

Comment: Well, "that solved my problem" is false because the other question is unanswered, but yeah, that's a dupe.  Thanks.

Comment: had that on MSE yesterday. fixed itself. I blame gremlins ;p