# Random errors on various sites when viewing main page

Tags: bug, homepage

Occasionally (very occasionally) when returning to the main page of a site by clicking on the logo I get the following message:

> It was not possible to perform this tag search at this time due to an unexpected error.

This is odd because I'm not performing a tag search.

So far this has happened on both Movies & TV and Cooking.  I have heard that others are getting this same message.

Comment: had a few instances of that myself. And someone on root access mentioned seeing a blank page. Tag engine acting up?

Comment: Got a screenshot?

Comment: @randal'thor no :( I didn't grab one when I had the chance... They don't come as easily for me when I'm on a Windows machine as on a real computer. :P

Comment: I've noticed this happening for about 3-4 days now. This was for any tags on StackOverflow.com Matter of fact, it happened just a few minutes ago.

Comment: @HarryVervet Related but definitely not duplicate. That question is a feature request asking that the error message be changed. I'm telling them there's a bug causing error messages to be displayed.

Comment: Possibly related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295435/278659

Comment: Catija – it is implied by the previous question that there is a bug. You: "I did not search for any tags." Shadow: "This is odd because I'm not performing a tag search." We could delve into the semantics further, but that's probably not a useful way to spend our or the bug-fixers time.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JEbN.png screenshot. Amusingly I was in the mod queue at the time

Comment: For me too; http://i.stack.imgur.com/JuUZq.png

Comment: I don't think this is duplicate. The bug report here asks to fix the bug causing error in front pages (also changed tags to reflect that), my feature request just asks to change the error message itself, until the bug is fixed. Voted to reopen.