# It was not possible to perform this tag search at this time due to an unexpected error

Tags: discussion, bug, error-message, question-lists

Anyone else seeing this error?

> It was not possible to perform this tag search at this time due to an unexpected error

[image: Meta Stack Overflow with unexpected error message]

It seems to be an intermittent problem that has [occurred before and supposedly fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295358/misleading-error-message-when-questions-list-fails-to-load)

Comment: Working again after a couple of refreshes. Looks like a server needs kicking ...

Comment: I've sent a tweet to Nick Craver :)

Comment: Craver to the rescue! ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill Nick is on sabbatical.

Comment: Which just means he's got more free time to look into this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Misleading error message when questions list fails to load](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295358/misleading-error-message-when-questions-list-fails-to-load)

Comment: Definitely happened [around the end of January](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348639/seeing-it-was-not-possible-to-perform-this-tag-search-at-this-time-due-to-an-un#comment820935_348639) too.

Comment: From Review: Duping to a four year old duplicate isn't best practice; that said the author declares it no-repro, while another says it's recently reoccurring. --- So I'm leaving it open as a new BR of an intermittent problem.

Comment: Similar report, from 2017: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295433/282094

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the generic message when something goes wrong with the Tag Engine on the server side.

It can happen when [people mess on purpose with SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295481/152859), as well as when a [new code version is deployed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295358/misleading-error-message-when-questions-list-fails-to-load#comment1189065_295481):

> for a few seconds when we deploy, it can be a little... "uncertain" - we deployed a little while before your comment, so I'm guessing you were one of the first people on a fresh server

I can only hope the case in this question is the later, i.e. a new deploy was made, and it took bit longer than usual until things became stable again.